# Удаление строки в файле Excel с помощью Python Pandas на основе нескольких условий

Tags: python, pandas

Пытаюсь решить задачу удаления строк в excel файле на основании нескольких условий (нужно удалить строки содержащте ячейки с цифрами не равными 0  и имеющие ячеки содержащие "+").

```
path_to_file = filedialog.askopenfilename()
dataFrameFromExcel = pd.read_excel(path_to_file)
    
for i in range(0, int(len(dataFrameFromExcel.index))):
    if dataFrameFromExcel.iloc[i][0]  == "+" and        dataFrameFromExcel.iloc[i][1] != 0 :  
       dataFrameFromExcel = dataFrameFromExcel.drop(labels = i) 
   
name = str("otvet.xlsx") 
dataFrameFromExcel.to_excel(name)
```

Входные данные:

```
-   0
-   5
-   2
+   3
-   1
+   1
-   0
+   1
-   2
-   9
-   1
-   3
```

Выходные данные:

```
   - 0
 0 - 5
 1 - 2
 3 - 1
 5 - 0
 7 - 2
 8 - 9
 9 - 1
10 - 3
```

При удалении строк при использовании одного условия явных проблем нет.

Буду признателен за помощь.

Дополнение к коментарию  для `@Step1709`

```
print(dataFrameFromExcel)

     Статус  Номер  
0      -       0
1      -       5
2      -       2
3      +       3
4      -       1
5      +       1
6      -       0
7      +       1
8      -       2
9      -       9
10     -       1
11     -       3
```

Comment: приведите данные в текстовом виде и исправьте идентацию кода в вопросе.

Comment: @strawdog Надеюсь привел в соответствие с требованиями.

Answer (score 1):

должно решить вашу задачу:

```
dataFrameFromExcel = dataFrameFromExcel.drop(dataFrameFromExcel[(dataFrameFromExcel[0] == '+') & (dataFrameFromExcel[1] != 0)].index)
```

Здесь с помощью фильтрации мы получаем индексы строк, которые необходимо удалить, а затем удаляем их с помощью `drop`.

Comment: постарайтесь добавлять более развёрнутые ответы, ну да ладно)

Comment: @PeterKolosov добавил небольшое пояснение)

Comment: @Step1709 Спасибо за коммент. Пока не получается использовать данный пример, хотя по логике вроде понятен. Буду пытаться разбираться дальше

Comment: @Norax хм очень странно, поидее тут негде быть ошибке, может с датафреймом что то не так? в нем есть столбец индексов же?

Comment: @Step1709 Насколько я понимаю, столбец `index` по умолчанию создается в датафрейм, а `columns` если он не объявлен, считается первой строкой в датафрейме. Строковые `index` есть и при выводе через  `print()`  и при записе в датафрейм. 
Если есть какие-либо примеры с данным кодом и входными данными, буду благодарен, возможно так проще будет разобраться где я допускаю ошибку.

Comment: @Norax `columns` вроде если явно не указаны то им даются имена 0, 1, 2 и тд по нумерации, индекс тоже вроде автоматом создается если явно не указано, что индекс не нужен. Можете добавить пожалуйста в вопрос  первые несколько строк датафрейма, чтоб я понимал, какие там данные и что может быть не так

Comment: @Step1709 вывод данных содержащихся в датафрейм, взятых с excel файла, добавил в конец поста.

Answer (score 0):

Можно отфильтровать фрейм с помощью булева массива. Сначала делаем булев массив с условиями `'+' и не 0`, затем инвертируем его `~` и фильтруем фрейм - в результирующем фрейме останутся только те строки, где в булевом массиве True.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['+', '-', '+', '-', '+', '-', '+', '-', '+', '-'], [0, 1, 2, 3, 7, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0]]).T
df = df[~(df[0].eq('+') & df[1].ne(0))]
print(df)
```

```
   0  1
0  +  0
1  -  1
3  -  3
5  -  2
6  +  0
7  -  1
9  -  0
```

Comment: Cпасибо за пример. В моем случае выдает все строки содержащие `"-" и "0"` без инвертации `~` . 

`df = df[((df[0].ne('+')) & (df[1].eq(0)))] `